# Remove objects from mulitdimensional array based on duplicate values

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have searched and read a lot but I'm overwhelmed by the sheer amount of posts and information concerning my question that I cant find the right solution to my problem. I have the following array.

[image]

As you can see some objects have the same value for the "href" element and for the "title" element. I'd like to create an new array that only contains unique objects for the "href" element where these objects also contain the corresponding "title" element.

It must be out there but I cant find it. A solution or a link to another issue with a solution that achieves this is most appreciated.

Comment: This is not a multidimensional array, it's a simple array of objects.

Comment: It's an object not array.  a For each works for this.  Initialize a new array `uniqueArray = []`.  If href[0] and title[1] not found in uniqueArray then push to it.  You end up with uniqueArray - no duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, the issue suggested by Barmar when marking this as duplicate does indeed contains the solution to this question.